# Getting Device Id null for deices with dual sim for below 5.1 os

Tags: android

Hey guys I am unable to get device Id for the device with dual sim.I am getting device as null for devices with dual sim slots(<5.1 os)

Below is my code to get device Id

```
public static String getImeiNumber(Context context) {
    try {
        if (context != null) {
            TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            if (telephonyManager != null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Device ID" + telephonyManager.getDeviceId());
                return telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Here I am retrieving Device Id with help of `telephony manager`.

Comment: I have tested your code on device having 4.4, and it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use this permission in menifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

Try this code

```
public String getIMEI(Context context){
        String imei=" ";
        try{
            TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            imei = telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
        }catch (Exception ex){
            Log.e(CommonContents.TAG, ex.getMessage());
        }
        return imei;
    }
```

**Edit**

Try using `getDeviceId(int slotId)` added in API level 23.

Returns the unique device ID of a subscription, for example, the IMEI for GSM and the MEID for CDMA phones. Return null if device ID is not available.

We can check whether phone single or dual sim by using Android API and IMEI for each sim Card

```
Log.i("OmSai ", "Single or Dula Sim "+telephonyManager.getPhoneCount());
Log.i("OmSai ", "Defualt device ID "+telephonyManager.getDeviceId());
Log.i("OmSai ", "Single 1 "+telephonyManager.getDeviceId(0));
Log.i("OmSai ", "Single 2 "+telephonyManager.getDeviceId(1));
```

***If you need an unique Id for a device you can use Secure Id. This is also unique***

```
public String getDeviceID(Context context){
        String deviceID = " ";
        try{
            deviceID = Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(),
                    Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
        }catch (Exception ex){
            Log.e(CommonContents.TAG, ex.getMessage());
        }
        return deviceID;
    }
```

Comment: It' s the same i am using permission. The problem is with <5.1 devices

Comment: For what purpose do you need device Id? Do you need unique key for each device?

Comment: Its the requirement to send device ID else I know we can use android ID or some other ID but requirement id device ID

Comment: Please read device id related issues at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785485/is-there-a-unique-android-device-id

Comment: @P.rai , you are commenting on my Answer. You can asked i and suggest in questions not Answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try out this class and its methods to get IMEI. `getInstance` method will return `TelephonyInfo` instance.

For different devices, we may need to guess the methods and give input to `getDeviceIdBySlot` method

```
public class TelephonyInfo {

    private static TelephonyInfo telephonyInfo;
    private String imsiSIM1;
    private String imsiSIM2;
    private boolean isSIM1Ready;
    private boolean isSIM2Ready;

    public String getImsiSIM1() {
        return imsiSIM1;
    }

    /*public static void setImsiSIM1(String imsiSIM1) {
        TelephonyInfo.imsiSIM1 = imsiSIM1;
    }*/

    public String getImsiSIM2() {
        return imsiSIM2;
    }

    /*public static void setImsiSIM2(String imsiSIM2) {
        TelephonyInfo.imsiSIM2 = imsiSIM2;
    }*/

    public boolean isSIM1Ready() {
        return isSIM1Ready;
    }

    /*public static void setSIM1Ready(boolean isSIM1Ready) {
        TelephonyInfo.isSIM1Ready = isSIM1Ready;
    }*/

    public boolean isSIM2Ready() {
        return isSIM2Ready;
    }

    /*public static void setSIM2Ready(boolean isSIM2Ready) {
        TelephonyInfo.isSIM2Ready = isSIM2Ready;
    }*/

    public boolean isDualSIM() {
        return imsiSIM2 != null;
    }

    private TelephonyInfo() {
    }

    public static TelephonyInfo getInstance(Context context){

        if(telephonyInfo == null) {

            telephonyInfo = new TelephonyInfo();

            TelephonyManager telephonyManager = ((TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE));


            telephonyInfo.imsiSIM1 = telephonyManager.getDeviceId();;
            telephonyInfo.imsiSIM2 = null;

            try {
                telephonyInfo.imsiSIM1 = getDeviceIdBySlot(context, "getDeviceIdGemini", 0);
                telephonyInfo.imsiSIM2 = getDeviceIdBySlot(context, "getDeviceIdGemini", 1);
            } catch (GeminiMethodNotFoundException e) {
                Log.e(BLL_LOG,"First GeminiMethodNotFoundException Ex="+e.toString());

                try {
                    telephonyInfo.imsiSIM1 = getDeviceIdBySlot(context, "getDeviceId", 0);
                    telephonyInfo.imsiSIM2 = getDeviceIdBySlot(context, "getDeviceId", 1);
                } catch (GeminiMethodNotFoundException e1) {
                    //Call here for next manufacturer's predicted method name if you wish
                    Log.e(BLL_LOG, "Second GeminiMethodNotFoundException Ex=" + e1.toString());
                }
            }

            telephonyInfo.isSIM1Ready = telephonyManager.getSimState() == TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_READY;
            telephonyInfo.isSIM2Ready = false;

            try {
                telephonyInfo.isSIM1Ready = getSIMStateBySlot(context, "getSimStateGemini", 0);
                telephonyInfo.isSIM2Ready = getSIMStateBySlot(context, "getSimStateGemini", 1);
            } catch (GeminiMethodNotFoundException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

                try {
                    telephonyInfo.isSIM1Ready = getSIMStateBySlot(context, "getSimState", 0);
                    telephonyInfo.isSIM2Ready = getSIMStateBySlot(context, "getSimState", 1);
                } catch (GeminiMethodNotFoundException e1) {
                    //Call here for next manufacturer's predicted method name if you wish
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        return telephonyInfo;
    }

    private static String getDeviceIdBySlot(Context context, String predictedMethodName, int slotID) throws GeminiMethodNotFoundException {

        String imsi = null;

        TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

        try{

            Class<?> telephonyClass = Class.forName(telephony.getClass().getName());

            Class<?>[] parameter = new Class[1];
            parameter[0] = int.class;
            Method getSimID = telephonyClass.getMethod(predictedMethodName, parameter);

            Object[] obParameter = new Object[1];
            obParameter[0] = slotID;
            Object ob_phone = getSimID.invoke(telephony, obParameter);

            if(ob_phone != null){
                imsi = ob_phone.toString();

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new GeminiMethodNotFoundException(predictedMethodName);
        }

        return imsi;
    }

    private static  boolean getSIMStateBySlot(Context context, String predictedMethodName, int slotID) throws GeminiMethodNotFoundException {

        boolean isReady = false;

        TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

        try{

            Class<?> telephonyClass = Class.forName(telephony.getClass().getName());

            Class<?>[] parameter = new Class[1];
            parameter[0] = int.class;
            Method getSimStateGemini = telephonyClass.getMethod(predictedMethodName, parameter);

            Object[] obParameter = new Object[1];
            obParameter[0] = slotID;
            Object ob_phone = getSimStateGemini.invoke(telephony, obParameter);

            if(ob_phone != null){
                int simState = Integer.parseInt(ob_phone.toString());
                if(simState == TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_READY){
                    isReady = true;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new GeminiMethodNotFoundException(predictedMethodName);
        }

        return isReady;
    }


    private static class GeminiMethodNotFoundException extends Exception {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = -996812356902545308L;

        public GeminiMethodNotFoundException(String info) {
            super(info);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried with this method , But not sure "getDeviceIdGemini"  will work for all devices , it may break for other devices

Comment: Agreed! getDeviceIdBySlot should be used to get the corresponding methods